# Regular Expression block negation

Tags: objective-c, regex, regex-negation, nsregularexpression

I want to find out a string in which a particular tag does not occur, such as:

```
<xyz>[\w]+<[^(unwanted)]></xyz>
```

where `unwanted` will be interpreted as `a`, `d`, `e`, `n`, `t` and `u`.  But what I want is a block string. How can I express it in regular expression?
I have tried negative lookahead, which doesn't work:

```
<xyz>.+(?!unwanted).+</xyz>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<xyz>(?:(?!unwanted).)+</xyz>
```

Matches all chars in `<xyz>...</xyz>`, but only as long as the expression `unwanted` doesn't start at any of them.

Comment: cHao, thank you so much for answering this difficult question.
However, the answer is also very difficult too. The solution has blown me.
Just want to check my understand,
Albeit the order (?!unwanted). or .(?!unwanted), it won't change the effect, right? 
why (?:)+ is used? Does it mean any character except "unwanted" which sit on the place of a single character?

Comment: `(?:...)` groups the stuff inside, but doesn't capture it.  If you don't care about capturing, you could just say `(...)` instead, but that's a tad wasteful.  The point either way is to make the `+` apply to the whole thing, so it will match any character that isn't the start of the expression `unwanted`.  As for the whole thing, it works like this:  every char it tries to match, it first does a negative lookahead (the `(?!...)`) to make sure the expression `unwanted` won't match there.  If not, then it grabs that character and tries again with the next one.

Comment: Without the `(?:...)` (or optionally, `(...)`), the `+` would only apply to the `.`, and you'd end up matching any string that didn't *start* with `unwanted`.  The resulting match could still have `unwanted` anywhere after the first char, though.  That is why you want to test at each location (and thus, why you group the lookahead and `.` together).

Comment: Changing the order of the lookahead and the `.` does affect the outcome, in at least one major way -- since with `.(?!...)` you'd be grabbing a char and *then* looking for `unwanted`, the pattern could still appear at the beginning of the string and you wouldn't see it.  That's why you check *before* you grab a char.

Comment: Thank you so much. I know how it works now.
You are so loveable.
This question has been on my mind for 2 years.