# Regex to not match a pattern in string

Tags: regex

I am a newbie and have been struggling the last hour to figure this out. Let's say you have these strings:

```
baa cec haw heef baas bat jackaay
```

I want to match all the words which don't have two aa's consecutively, so in the above it will match `cec`, `haw`, `heef`, `bat`.

This is what i have done so far, but it's completely wrong i can sense :D

```
\w*[^\s]*[^a\s]{2}[^\s]*\w*
```

Comment: So Javascript or Python or Perl?

Comment: Python: `[s for s in myStrings if 'aa' not in s]`

Comment: @mshsayem `[s for s in myStrings.split() if 'aa' not in s]`

Comment: @Kevin Guan: Changed just a sec before you posted the comment, :p. He said, `strings` which I interpreted _a collection/list_

Comment: @mshsayem I disagree, use regex on a *collection/list* without `for` loop? whose idea? :P

Comment: It is regex in general, testing using https://regex101.com/

Comment: Related: [Regular Expression block negation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14819125/319403)

Comment: Where are these strings held? In a file, a space delimited string or something else?

Comment: @StefanBratanov: Regrettably, differences among regex flavors can't be ignored. even for a question as simple as this one.  And using multiple flavor tags just confuses things; I've removed them.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe want to use negative lookahead:

```
/(^|\s)(?!\w*aa\w*)(\w+)/gi
```

You can check your string by paste this code on console on Chrome/Firefox (F12):

```
var pattern = /(^|\s)(?!\w*aa\w*)(\w+)/gi;
var str = 'baa cec haw heef baas bat jackaay';
while(match = pattern.exec(str))
    console.log(match[2]); // position 2 is (\w+) in regex
```

You can read more about lookahead [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word).
See [it](https://regex101.com/r/sK9eW9/1) on Regex101 to see how this regex work.

Comment: Thank you. This almost works. It just captures the spaces between words as well as part of the group.

Comment: If you select 2nd group, you will get expected string. But I think @stribizhev has better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need a regex that has 2 things: a word boundary `\b` and a negative lookahead right after it (it will be sort of anchored that way) that will lay restrictions to the subpattern that follows.

```
\b(?!\w*aa)\w+
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gB4eV4/1)

Regex breakdown:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?!\w*aa)` - the negative lookahead that will cancel a match if the word has 0 or more word characters followed by two `a`s
- `\w+` - 1 or more word characters.

Code demo:

```js
var re = /\b(?!\w*aa)\w+/gi; 
var str = 'baa cec haw heef bAas bat jackaay bar ha aa lar';
var res = str.match(re);
document.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try hard to understand how this works, but it works and is exactly what i wanted to achieve.

Comment: Please see [*Word Boundaries*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and [*Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) articles. The main pattern is `\w`(alphanumeric+underscore matching subpattern) that we match 1 or more times (`+`), only after a non-word character (not `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) if it has no `aa` (since we check the word first with the lookahead if it has `aa` after zero or more word caracters (`\w*`)).

Answer (score 0):

in javascript, you could use `filter` and regex invert `!` a non-capturing group `?:`.

```
var strings = ['baa','cec','haw','heef','baas','bat','jackaay'];
strings = $(strings).filter(function(index, element){
   return !/.*(?:aa).*/.test(element);                // regex => .*(?:aa).*
});
```